# Can someone explain me Javascript operators - why this output?

Tags: javascript, operators, calculator

I have created a calculator but it has such problem
`var x=060; 
var y=60; 
console.log(x+y);`
The output is **108** why so?

And, How can i make calculator to enter single operator and wait for an operand and then an operator could appear in.
This is my calculator
[Calculator2.0](https://code.sololearn.com/WnOICqUp9RWN/#js)

Answer (score 3):

Put 0 in front of a number means the base is octal. In your case 060 (octal) = 48 (decimal). You add 60 + 48 that is equal to 108.

Comment: *"Put 0 in front of a number means the base is octal."* That format was only ever an "allowed extension" and is expressly forbidden in strict mode. In modern JavaScript, octal is written with a `0o` prefix (just like hex is written with an `0x` prefix and binary with `0b`); http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-literals-numeric-literals.

Comment: thanks for precisions

Comment: but in my calculator if a user input it the same then the functionality of the operator will not be counted..  how can i make changes to it that the zero gets neglected

Comment: You can simply check the input given by the user and remove the leading '0'

Comment: @SamiKhan: If you're expecting an integer, use `parseInt(theString, 10)` to force the radix (number base) to decimal. If you're expecting floating point, use `parseFloat`, which always works in decimal. Note, however, that in both cases they happily ignore non-number characters following the number, e,g, `parseFloat("060abc")` is 60. So you may need some pre-validation.